# IE 10 displays Tahoma instead of a Google font

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Here is my HTML code. The problem is that IE 10 cannot use Exo 2 font with  h2 tags. It uses Tahoma. Firefox and others are able to display all fonts correctly.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:500,600" />

  <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:500" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:600" />
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <p>Here the font is Exo 2. So, everything is just fine!</p>

  <h2>Here the font should not be Tahoma, but it is when using IE 10</h2>
</body>
```

And here is my current CSS code. The h2 tag should be with Exo 2 and font-weight 600, but IE 10 Tahoma instead of Exo 2.

```
body {
  font-family: "Exo 2", Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000000;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Exo 2", Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #B4166F;
}
```

How could I fix this all? By the way, I prefer not using JavaScript and/or jQuery.

**Edit:**

I just noticed that this might have something to do with font-weight 600. If the value is 500 all the time, IE displays the font Exo 2 correctly. But when I replace 500 with 600, IE will display Tahoma instead of Exo 2.

```
body {
  font-family: "Exo 2", Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000000;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Exo 2", Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500; /* if this is 500, no problems at all! */
  font-size: 12px; /* this works fine, too */
  color: #B4166F;
}

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:500,600" />

  <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:500" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:600" />
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <p>Here the font is Exo 2. So, everything is just fine!</p>

  <h2>Here the font is Exo 2 when using IE 10 if the font-weight of h2 is 500 instead of 600. So, works just fine. But when the font-weight is 600, here the font will be Tahoma istead of Exo 2 when using IE 10. Should be Exo 2.</h2>
</body>
```

**Edit 2:**

I just noticed that if I type the URL on the address bar and press enter, the font Exo 2 will be displayed correctly in IE. When I refresh the page, Tahoma will be seen again. I do not understand why is this happening.

So, what should I try next?

Comment: What happens if you remove Tahoma from your font-family attributes?

Comment: If I have only Exo 2 and sans-serif, IE 10 will use Arial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Tools -> Internet Options -> Reset Internet Explorer settings. This helped me. Now IE 10 works just fine with Google fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I would just Import it in the Style sheet at the top

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2);

Comment: This did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments no longer work in IE after IE9. I would look elsewhere as to why Exo2 doesn't work only in h2 cause that shouldn't happen.